# Is it possible to have a default method for an object along with other methods in javascript?

Tags: javascript, object, methods

I wonder how can I define a 'foo' function that behave as the following:

```
foo(id); //return document.getElementById(id)
foo(id).value //return document.getElementById(id).value
```

I believe it is possible to have such function because jquery seems behave the similar

```
$('')
$('').html
```

Thanks.

Thanks for answer, but I think I didn't use a generic property name previously. Let's say, it is not 'value' but other custom property.

```
foo(id); //return document.getElementById(id)
foo(id).something //return document.getElementById(id).value
```

Comment: Just do `var foo = document.getElementById;`

Answer (score 1):

`value` is an `property` of this element. You can do something like :

```
function foo(id) { return document.getElementById(id); }

// console.log(foo.id);
// console.log(foo.innerHTML);
// console.log(foo.length);
// console.log(foo.value);
// ...
```

Comment: `value` is a *property* of the element. It's a reflected property for the attribute `"value"`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is not a "default method" but
foo(x) return an object;
foo(x).something return the object's property of something.

Example:

```
foo = function(a) {
    bar.change(a);
    return bar;
}
bar = {
    something: 0, //default is 0
    change: function(b){
        bar.something = b;
    }
}

foo(3);
// return: Object {something: 3, change: function}

foo(4).something 
//return 4.
```